# react-spring how to use animated(Component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-spring

I am trying to sort out some performance problems in an image slider and I have discovered that using `animated.img` yields much better performance than using `animated.div` with some react component inside.

The react component obviously isn't just placed inside for the fun of it, but luckily react-spring lets you animate a custom component by doing

```js
const AnimatedComponent = animated(Component)
```

as per [the docs](https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/basics)

But how do I use it? I have been trying but typescript just gives some really unhelpful message about missing 269 different types of props.

**EDIT** added error

The typescript error is shown by vscode, but it might not be important. Since I have no idea what props to pass in order to animate the component I am not surprised that it does not work, but the error message is not really helping in determining what I need to do.

```
' is missing the following properties from type 'AnimatedProps<{ title: string | FluidValue<string, any>; id: string | FluidValue<string, any>; article?: { title: string; metaTitle: string; metaDescription: string; description: string; showRelatedArticles: boolean; elements: ({ ...; } | ... 4 more ... | { ...; })[]; } | null | undefined; ... 269 more ...; key?: st...': title, id, slot, animate, and 257 more.ts(2740)
```

I stripped some of the first props since I recognise them from the component I am trying to animate and I know that they are present.

Have someone tried using this? An example of how to use it would be really nice.

I am on the `9.0.0-rc.3` version of react-spring if that matters.

Comment: Where do you get the typescript message and what is it exactly?

Comment: @PeterAmbruzs I have added the error message

Comment: Yes, I know how to create the custom animated component, but not how the alter the custom component such that the animation works. There must be some props passed down or something else. How does the animated component know what to render when it is being animated?

Comment: @PeterAmbruzs I dont know why you deleted your answer. I was going to accept it as it was correct. I had the obvious solution, but something else made it break and I thought that then there must be some other way to do it.

Comment: I just felt it is too trivial in this form. I posted it as a conversation starter, to unravel your problem. I undeleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to start the conversation.

Let's start with the documentation's example. Let's suppose you have a third party Donut component. It has a percent property. And you want to animate based on this property. So you can use animated as a wrapper around Donut.

```
const AnimatedDonut = animated(Donut)
// ...
const props = useSpring({ value: 100, from: { value: 0 } })
return <AnimatedDonut percent={props.value} />
```

Is it where the problem occurs?

Comment: I just got stuck in this same problem but the case with me is my custom component has got 6 props which I need for rendering the component but has nothing to do with animation. then how do I pass that ?

Comment: @SoumalyaBhattacharya The new animated component has the same properties than the original component. You should just switch the new component wit the same signature.

Answer (score 5):

### Background

`react-spring` does not rely on timing, like the css transition api, but instead does transitions and animations from a physics context. To achieve this with acceptable performance in React, it bypasses React and makes modifications to the relevant DOM nodes themselves.

### Regular `react-spring` animation components

As you might have seen, all regular DOM nodes exist as `react-spring` equivalents. For example `animation.span`, `animation.div` etc... These wrap the native DOM elements with the necessary functionality for `react-spring` to work. What is worth to notice here are these two subtleties:

- The functionality of `react-spring` is attached to a single DOM node
- Because the functionality is attached to a native DOM node, only native DOM element props are used

Both of these facts have implications for how we can use custom components wrapped in `animated`.

### Our custom component

Let's work with a simple scenario using React functional components and Typescript and see how you can translate it into a custom `react-spring` component.

Let's say you have a `div` whose background color you want to animate when transitioning from one color to another after clicking it.

###### 1. Without `react-spring`

The basic approach would be:

```
const Comp: FC = () => {

    const [color, setColor] = useState<string>("green")

    return (
        <div
            style={{ 
                backgroundColor: color,
                transition: "background-color 1s"
            }}
            onClick={ () => setColor(color => color === "blue" ? "green" : "blue") }
        />
    )
}
```

###### 2. With `react-spring` basic usage

Doing the same thing with `react-spring` basic usage of `useSpring` would result in

```
const Comp: FC = () => {
    
    const [color, setColor] = useState<string>("green")
    const springColor = useSpring({ backgroundColor: color})

    return (
        <animated.div
            style={springColor}
            onClick={ () => setColor(color => color === "blue" ? "green" : "blue") }
        />
    )
}
```

###### 3. With `react-spring` best practices usage

Even better is to use the [api functions](https://react-spring.io/hooks/use-spring#or-pass-a-function-that-returns-values-and-update-using-the-api) so that we don't have to rerender the component on every color change. To be clear, when you use this method, you're not changing any of the props passed to the component you want to animate, and so you can change its state via the api without rerendering it, as long as `Comp` itself doesn't rerender.

```
const Comp: FC = () => {

    const [springColor, api] = useSpring(() => ({ backgroundColor: "green" }))

    return (
        <animated.div
            style={springColor}
            onClick={ () => api.start({ backgroundColor: springColor.backgroundColor.goal === "blue" ? "green" : "blue" })}
        />
    )
}
```

###### 4. With delegation to class

Let's think about it. You're passing some wrapped property to these `animated` components. These properties are of type `SpringValue<T>` and they can be instantiated by means of `new` or via, for example, `useSpring`. Our first step towards building a custom component would be to simply pass these as properties to a component that has an `animated` component in it:

```
export interface CompProps {
    color: SpringValue<string>;
    onChangeColor: () => void;
}

const Comp: FC<CompProps> = (props: CompProps) => {

    return (
        <animated.div
            style={{ backgroundColor: props.color }}
            onClick={props.onChangeColor}
        />
    )
}

const Parent: FC = () => {

    const [springColor, api] = useSpring(() => ({ backgroundColor: "green" }));

    return (
        <Comp
            color={springColor.backgroundColor}
            onChangeColor={() => api.start({
                backgroundColor: springColor.backgroundColor.goal === "blue" ? "green" : "blue"
            })}
        />
    )
}
```

###### 5. With a naive custom component wrapped in `animated`

Now we are ready to do the replacement and wrap our property in `animated` instead of using the `animated` native element inside our component.

```
export interface CompProps {
    style: CSSProperties;
    onChangeColor: () => void;
}

const Comp: FC<CompProps> = (props: CompProps) => {

    return (
        <div
            style={props.style}
            onClick={props.onChangeColor}
        />
    )
}

const WrappedComp: AnimatedComponent<FC<CompProps>> =
    animated(Comp)

const Parent: FC = () => {

    const [springColor, api] = useSpring(() => ({ backgroundColor: "green" }));

    return (
        <WrappedComp
            style={{ backgroundColor: springColor.backgroundColor }}
             onChangeColor={() =>
                 api.start({
                     backgroundColor:
                         springColor.backgroundColor.goal === "blue" ? "green" : "blue"
                  })
             }
         />
    )
}
```

Note well that now our wrapped component looks like a regular component and it shows no sign of being used together with `react-spring`. Nonetheless, as we shall see, there are still some additional requirements on it for the integration with `react-spring` to work as intended. Note how we are no longer suppling `backgroundColor` as a prop but instead we use `style`. Also, all the animated props passed to our custom component are props available on the native `div` element on which our custom component attaches the forwarded ref. More on this further down.

The above component is naive, because the `animated` wrapper can't update the wrapped component without rerendering. Why? Simply because our wrapped component does not accept a ref and so demanding from `react-spring` to be able to update our component without rerendering it is unreasonable.

###### 6. With a proper custom component wrapped in `animated`

Let's enhance our wrapped component by letting it accept a ref.

```
const Comp: FC<CompProps & RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> = 
    forwardRef<HTMLDivElement,CompProps>(
        (props, ref) => {

            return (
                <div 
                    ref={ref} 
                    style={props.style} 
                    onClick={props.onChangeColor} 
                />
            )
        }
    )
```

Now `react-spring` will sense that our wrapped component accepts a ref and so it will refrain from rerendering it on every change and instead use the ref to update it. Because updates take place via a ref, it is important that the props are actual props on the element we want to change; if React is needed to map the custom props to the actual props on the DOM element, then we are required to rerender on every new animation value, which is suboptimal. Nonetheless, this is exactly what happens when we DON'T enable our custom component to take a ref. Therefore, version 5 would have worked even if we had continued to use the custom props `backgroundColor` instead of `style`. Version number 6 had however not worked, and the property `backgroundColor`, would simply have been added to the DOM element on which the ref was set, which would not result in any change since this property is not a property on the native `div` DOM element.

#### Sandboxes

I have made two sandboxes available:

- The first sandbox shows the components in this answer. Each component makes a printout in the console whenever it renders. Check these printouts and verify the behaviours described above. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-custom-component-bvtxy)
- The second sandbox is on the same theme but slightly more advanced. Here the number of renderings is kept up to date, so that we can verify different behaviours. One of the take-aways from this sandbox is that all the animated changes that we do using the api are "free" in the sense that it does not increase the number of renderings for the affected components. When the parent rerenders, as usual, all children rerender as well. A list of important points has been added at the bottom. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-elaborate-example-mn5pu)

#### Conclusion

- Always use the api methods when using `react-spring` hooks.
- Always make your components accept a ref when wrapping them in `animated`.
- If you want to be able to update your wrapped component without rerendering it, you can only attach the behaviour of `react-spring` to ONE element. `react-spring` does its updates using a ref and since you can't attach a ref to multiple elements at the same time (nor does `forwardRef` provide a way to add multiple refs), you can't use your springs in multiple places in a wrapped component without rerendering it or you will not arrive at the expected functionality. With such a component, it is better to pass `SpringValue<T>` as props and use `animated` native elements inside the component instead.

Don't:

```
const NestedComp = ({ style1, style2 }) => {
    ...
    return (
        <div style={ style1 }>
            <div style={ style2 }>
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const Wrapped = animated(NestedComp)
```

Do:

```
const NestedComp = ({ springStyle1, springStyle2 }) => {
    ...
    return (
        <animated.div style={ springStyle1 }>
            <animated.div style={ springStyle2 }>
                ....
            </animated.div>
        </animated.div>
    )
}
```

- Make sure that the custom props you use in animations on your element is compatible with the props on the native DOM element on which you attach the ref, otherwise `react-spring` can't properly update the element directly (instead it just sets the property which, if it doesn't exist on the DOM element, has no effect).

Don't:

```
const Comp = ({ color }) => {
    ...
    return (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.color }} />
    )
}

const WrappedComp = animated(Comp)

const Parent = () => {
    ...
    const [springProp, api] ) = useSpring(() => ({ color: "green" }))
    ...
    return <WrappedComp color={ springProp.color } />
}
```

Do:

```
const Comp = ({ style }) => {
    ...
    return (
        <div style={props.style} />
    )
}

const WrappedComp = animated(Comp)

const Parent = () => {
    ...
    const [springProp, api] ) = useSpring(() => ({ color: "green" }))
    ...
    return (
         <WrappedComp 
             style={{ backgroundColor: springProp.color }}
         />
    )
}
```

In the above, we want to update `Comp` without using React, but React is required to assemble the proper `style` prop since `color` is not a native prop of a `div` element, therefore updating `color` via a ref will only lead to the `color` prop being set on the `div` element which does nothing. On the other hand, when we add the `style` property already in the parent, the `animated` component will detect that one of the `style` props is a `SpringValue` and updating it accordingly will have the expected effect.

Finally, remember that if we are not after updating our custom component with the api, we could simply refrain from designing our custom component so that it can take a ref and use whichever prop names we want; `react-spring` will anyways now rerender the component on every animation frame and so React will map all the custom props to the correct native DOM element props. Nonetheless, this strategy of execution is hopefully not desirable.

Comment: What a detailed answer. I guess I'm still confused, can we use animated() to animate props other than style, or is that a limitation of react-spring?

Comment: What prop would you want to animate that doesn't end up as a style prop in the end? Give me a usecase :)

Comment: I'm thinking for animating gl-react shaders, where the props control shader uniforms. Gl-react docs does have a [demo](https://gl-react-cookbook.surge.sh/animated?menu=true) using an "animated" library, but the example is pretty out of date and uses style values as a hack to update the shader props. I know animating non-style props with react-spring must be possible though because [@react-spring/three](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-spring/three) does it. But I'm a little bit confused as to how to apply their approach to my own component.

Comment: Ok, don't know all about that but yes you can animate non-native properties but it won't be as efficient since the React component will rerender on every animation frame. It should be good enough in most cases though. Just wrap your component in `animated` and skip the part where you make sure that your component can take a ref and you should be good to go :) If your component only uses the value to control some native DOM property on the other hand, then you're better off short-circuiting it directly (doesn't have to be style, just some native DOM property)